# SUMIF in a Calculated Column in a pivot table in a Google Sheet gives "Argument must be a range." error

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated column that sums a column if another column equals something.

I am using this formula, which I think should work, but it's giving the error `Argument must be a range.`.

```
=SUMIF(type, "a", age)
```

My sample data:

[image]

My pivot table with the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you consider non-pivot table solution that would yield exactly what you expect from pivot table?

Comment: I did but I need in a pivot table (don't ask).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `SUMIF`, you could use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(type="a", age)
```

Got this answer [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sumif-in-pivot-table-calculated-fields-in-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Calculated Field you can slightly change the setup of your pivot table to achieve the desired result by:

1. Add `type` to the **Rows** section—under `group`—and uncheck "Show totals".
2. Add `age` to the **Values as Columns** section—under `count of a`— and set "Summarize by" to `SUM`.
3. Add `type` to the **Filters** section and select `a` from the "Status" dropdown menu.

**When you're done your pivot table should look like this:**
[image: pivot table]

**And your pivot table editor should look like this:**
[image: pivot table editor]

**Based on example data table shown here** (color-coding added manually):
[image: example data]

***Note:** the `count of a` calculated field can also be achieved using built-ins instead of a calculated field by adding `type` to the **Values as Columns** section and choosing `COUNTA` from the "Summarize by" dropdown menu.*

*With a pivot table the values you add will already be conditional on the rows you've specified, so when you add `type` "summarized by COUNTA" the "where group = alpha AND type = a" is already implied by the values to the left.*

*Hope that helps!*

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me because I have numerous other columns and `type` columns that we want to sum by. So I need columns like `=SUMIF(type, "a", col1)`, `=SUMIF(location, "here", col2)`, etc...

Comment: Makes sense—in that case unfortunately the short answer is that what you’re trying to do is not possible with a single pivot table. You either need to create several different pivot tables or explore other options (such as writing a few SUMIFS formulas or leveraging the QUERY function). Happy to help with either of those routes if needed!

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: No. I had to create a new column in my original data source. :(

Comment: :( sorry we couldn’t solve it—hope the workaround is effective though!